# Отдельная парольная политика

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

Система Windows 2008. Есть дефолтная парольная политика для целого домена. Требуется для трех пользователей добавить свою политику (и возможно для каждого из них она будет отличаться). Как вообще это делается?

Comment: мей би, смени пароль на нужный у необходимых юзеров при отключенной политике а потом верни как было) я так пароль админский ставил)

Answer (score 1):

ключевое слово - finegrained password policy,привязываются к группам пользователей

Answer (score 0):

С обычными политиками по умолчанию это практически нереализуемо. Для создания выборочных политик используют [доменные службы Active Directory: подробные политики паролей](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc770394%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Создайте отдельное подразделение в рамках домена, через консоль управления групповыми политиками создайте новую политику для этого подразделения и укажите необходимые параметры политики паролей. или ещё подробнее?